# Server-Side routing for single page app

Tags: nginx, dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to get my Dart Polymer 1.0 single page app working with `pushState`. I have set up nginx to route all requests to the dev server which runs when executing `pub serve`. Nginx also takes care of always requesting `index.html` instead of the real url.

The problem I am facing is that as soon as I load a url with at least one folder, the js cannot be loaded anymore.

### Example

Requesting `project.local` loads the index.html file and works fine. The same is true for `project.local/test`. As soon as I try going to `project.local/test/something`, it stops working because the file `index.bootstrap.initialize.dart` is requested from `project.local/test/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart` and not from `project.local/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart`.

### Source code

The whole project can be found at https://github.com/agileaddicts/blitzlicht. The [index.html](https://github.com/agileaddicts/blitzlicht/blob/master/web/index.html) is where the magic happens.

How do I tell the transformer to put absolute urls into the html instead of relative ones?

Comment: Your project uses Polymer 1.0.0-rc.6 (from `pubspec.lock`). The most recent is 1.0.0-rc.15. In this version you need only the `polymer` transformer instead of `web_components` and `reflectable`.

Comment: What does "Requesting project.local" mean? Your project doesn't have a `test` directory. Can you please add the concrete error message you get in the browser?

Comment: "index.bootstrap.initialize.dart is requested from project.local/test/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart" Isn't this was the rewrite on the server should handle?

Comment: I can't upgrade because of some weird dependency issues. rc6 was the latest I was able to use. Running `pub upgrade` doesn't update polymer either. Regarding "Requesting project.local": What I meant was doing a http request in the browser. The error I get is a 404 on the initialize.dart file because of the wrong directly. I am not sure if I have to rewrite all the js and dart files (I'm still in development mode). An easier way would be to have the generated index.html file reference the files absolute instead of relative.

Answer (score 3):

you should by able to upgrade to the last version of polymer by changing the version of reflectable.
`reflectable: >=0.5.0`

and perhaps add this in you pubspec
`- $dart2js:
      $include: '**/*.bootstrap.initialize.dart'`